# Unable to compare two strings when one of them is from cin. What is wrong here?

Tags: c++, string

```
void Display::getInput(){
  cout << endl << endl << "Enter Command: ";
  char input[MAX_LENGTH];
  cin >> input;

  if (input == "start"){
    startMenu();
  }
```

I get this error but I'm not sure why since I would always be able to compare using this syntax..

> Display.cpp: In member function ‘void Display::getInput()’:
>
> Display.cpp:20:16: warning: comparison with string literal results in
> unspecified behaviour [-Waddress]    if (input == "start"){

Comment: Use `strcmp` instead?

Comment: such problems completely disappear if you use `std::string`

Answer (score 4):

To compare C-style strings, you need to use `strcmp`. Otherwise, change `input` to be a string (`std::string`) instead of an array of characters. You are comparing two pointers, one of which points to a literal and the other of which points to an array, so they can never be equal.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare C-style character strings like that but instead use `strcmp` to compare which returns `0` when success and non-zero for failure.

Or you can use class `string`:

```
int main(){
    char szInput[100];
    std::cin.getline(szInput, 100);

    const char* szTest = "Hello";

    if(!strcmp(szInput, szTest))
        std::cout << "Identical" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Not identical" << std::endl;


    std::string sInput;
    std::getline(std::cin, sInput); // getline for white-spaces

    std::string sTest = "Welcome there!";

    if(sTest == sInput)
        std::cout << "Identical" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Not identical" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

- I used `getline` instead of `cin` to take in count white space characters.